# How to send messages from a kernel module to a user-space program using NETLINK_ROUTE?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, kernel-module, netlink

I have written a user-space program to listen on the `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket protocol family. Now I want to write a kernel module to send messages over `NETLINK_ROUTE` so that the user-space program can receive those messages. I have gone through many articles such as [THIS](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) but all of them demonstrate it by defining a new protocol family or by either using `NETLINK_GENERIC`. I know that one cannot create a `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket using `netlink_kernel_create` as it is already created by the kernel. I want to know how can i send messages using this already created socket.